# C# Regex.Split with many string patterns more than 20

Tags: c#, xml, regex, text-files

Hi i was trying to filter a large of text file using Regex.Split with about more than 20 of string patterns i need to use but the outcome is not correct and there are so many empty strings.

below is my code

```
string[] tmp = Regex.Split(originalString, @"(LINE|3DFACE|3DSOLID|ARC|ATTDEF|ATTRIB|BODY|CIRCLE|DIMENSION|ELLIPSE|HATCH|HELIX|IMAGE|INSERT|LEADER|LIGHT||LWPOLYLINE|MLINE|MLEADER|MLEADERSTYLE|MTEXT|OLEFRAME|OLE2FRAME|POINT|POLYLINE|RAY|REGION|SECTION|SEQEND|SHAPE|SOLID|SPLINE|SUN|SURFACE|TABLE|TEXT|TOLERANCE|TRACE|UNDERLAY|VERTEX|VIEWPORT|WIPEOUT|XLINE)");
```

if i only use about 5 of them then the outcome is able to do exactly as i need, is there any limit for regex.split for string patterns?

**EDIT 1**

THANKS TO @MRAB

here is the code for actually running working and right output

```
        string fileName = textBox1.Text;
        var stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        TextReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName);
        string originalString = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        string[] tmp = Regex.Split(originalString, @"(3DFACE|3DSOLID|ACAD_PROXY_ENTITIY|ARC|ATTDEF|ATTRIB|BODY|CIRCLE|DIMENSION|ELLIPSE|HATCH|HELIX|IMAGE|INSERT|LEADER|LIGHT|LWPOLYLINE|MLINE|MLEADERSTYLE|MLEADER|MTEXT|OLEFRAME|OLE2FRAME|POINT|POLYLINE|RAY|REGION|SEQEND|SHAPE|SOLID|SPLINE|SUN|SURFACE|TABLE|TEXT|TOLERANCE|TRACE|UNDERLAY|VERTEX|VIEWPORT|WIPEOUT|XLINE|LINE)");
        List<string> result = new List<string>();


        for (var i = 1; i < tmp.Count() - 1; i += 2)
        {

            result.Add(tmp[i] + tmp[i + 1]);
        }
```

Comment: what exactly does the output look like, aside from the empty strings? just a guess.. could it be the || between LIGHT and LWPOLYLINE

Comment: sounds a little like you don't actually need a regex but to tokenize the strings instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the static `Split` method of the `Regex` class. There's also a `Split` method on `Regex` instances, for example:

```
new Regex(@"(LINE|3DFACE|3DSOLID)").Split(originalString, 5, 0);
```

Your code contains this in the regex:

```
"LIGHT||LWPOLYLINE"
```

which looks like a mistake to me.

You should also note that when you have a regex like this:

```
"MLEADER|MLEADERSTYLE"
```

and a string like this:

```
"MLEADERSTYLE"
```

it will match `"MLEADER"` because that occurs earlier in a regex. Where a short literal occurs as a prefix of a longer literal, put the longer one earlier.

Comment: umm what the meaning of 5 and 0 in your code? `Split(originalString, 5, 0);`

Comment: The prototype method is `public string[] Split(string input, int count, int startat)`. In the question you asked how to limit the number of splits; this will limit it to 5 splits.

Comment: ah yes thank you @MRAB i didn't realize that mistake and i just happen to know that we should put the longer one earlier. Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

Like @IanNorton said depending on your source data you might want to consider using a string tokenizer instead of a RegEx / Split. The folks developing [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/download.html) have a good example you can use / learn from.